# Can't access elpa when initializing

Tags: init-file

I'm trying to install exwm on NixOS 20.09.

I use emacs 27.1.

My init file:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives '(("gnu"   . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
```

Emacs complaints when evaluating
`package-refresh-contents`
with the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "elpa.gnu.org/443 Name or service not known")
  signal(error ("elpa.gnu.org/443 Name or service not known"))
  package--with-response-buffer-1("https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/" #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x976509>) :file "archive-contents" :async nil :error-function #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x97651d>) :noerror nil)
  package--download-one-archive(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") "archive-contents" nil)
  package--download-and-read-archives(nil)
  package-refresh-contents()
  (if (package-installed-p 'use-package) nil (package-refresh-contents) (package-install 'use-package))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/user/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 813
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/user/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/user/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/user/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x7c3935>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x7c77c9>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

I changed gnu's url to "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/" and got a similar error

```
"elpa.gnu.org/80 Name or service not known"
```

I tried also the commands

```
curl http://elpa.gnu.org
curl https://elpa.gnu.org
```

and they seem to work.

How can I fix this, so I can access ELPA as I expect?